# logstash with bash script execution in different server

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a running elasticsearch in one server and I need to execute some bash script that has been located in a different machine/server. My question is whether I can use exec command plugin in logstash to command logstash execute that creates bash script in another server ?

Comment: Have you tried using SSH to run the command on the other server?

Comment: Hi @Dennis , thanks for the respond. From my understanding command terms is use to execute the bash script from the same server where logstash and bash script located. So my doubt here is there any way to use this command term where the bash script is not located in the same server as logstash ?

Comment: Hi @Dennis , Sorry for misunderstood the question. Yes i manually ssh to other server and it works nice. But when i use logstash plugin to ssh like exec and command it does not return any result.. But if i put only ls  command => "ls" and its works fine. The question is whether we can use other command in logstash except ls ?